# How to know onSurfaceTextureAvailable is called for which TextureView

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer, textureview

I am writing an application where I need to display two `TextureView`(s) on my activity. I am attaching videos to each of the `TextureView` instance using `MediaPlayer` objects using the following code inside `onSurfaceTextureAvailable()`:

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {

    Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

    mMediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mMediaPlayer1.setDataSource(<filePath>);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to load the file from the file system", e);
        return;
    }

    mMediaPlayer1.setSurface(surface);
    mMediaPlayer1.setLooping(true);
    mMediaPlayer1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            isPlaybackReady = true;
        }
    });

    mMediaPlayer1.prepareAsync();
}
```

Now, if I have two instances of `TextureView`, how would I know the callback into `onSurfaceTextureAvailable(...)` is for which `TextureView`.

The other way is to setup the `MediaPlayer` objects outside the `onSurfaceTextureAvailable(...)`, by getting a hold over the associated `SurfaceTexture` by calling `TextureView.getSurfaceTexture()`. I tried that as well but it always returns `null`. Is there something else that I need to do for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set two instances of TextureView with different listener.

```
textureView1.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        doSomething(textureView1, surfaceTexture, i, i1);
    }
    // implement other methods 


    });

textureView2.setSurfaceTextureListener(new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i1) {
        doSomething(textureView2, surfaceTexture, i, i1);
    }

    // implement other methods 
    });
```

}